# Get index of rows with identical elements in python vanilla or using numpy

Tags: python, numpy

I'm trying to find the index of elements in a row with identical items.

Here's my code so far:

```
 from __future__ import print_function
 import numpy as np


 b = np.array([[0, 0, 0],
          [2, 2, 2],
          [2, 2, 2],
          [2, 0, 2],
          [2, 0, 2]])

for rows in b:
    if len(set(rows)) <= 1:
        indices = list(zip(*np.where(rows == 2)))
        print(indices)
```

Right now, it's only getting the x values. I know there's a where the function in numpy, but that can't be applied here since I'm looking for something specific.

Edit:

It seems like my question was marked as unclear, so I decided to post my attempts at implementing this.

```
import numpy as np

b = np.array([[0, 0, 0],
              [2, 2, 2],
              [2, 2, 2],
              [2, 0, 2],
              [2, 0, 2]])

for rows in b:
    if len(set(rows)) <= 1:
        indices = list(zip(*np.where(rows == 2)))
        rows_to_list = rows.tolist()
        b_to_list = b.tolist()
        if indices != []:
            print(b_to_list.index(rows_to_list))
            print(indices)
```

As you can see, after getting the desired rows, I tried to find where these rows are located. For some reason, I'm only getting 1 as the index, even though the b[1] and b[2] are filled with 2's.

Comment: what is your expected result given your example?

Comment: Have in mind that there are two identical rows (ignore the 0's on the edge). Hence, this:                                                                                  `[(1,), (2,), (3,)]
[(1,), (2,), (3,)]`

Comment: I've edited my code to reflect that better, @senderle

Comment: For this version of the question, asking for just row indexes corresponding to rows that contain all the same value, this is an answer: `eq = np.equal.reduce(b, axis=1).nonzero()`. You can pass the result in as an indexing tuple: `assert (b[eq] == [[2, 2, 2], [2, 2, 2]]).all() == True`.

Comment: Is there a way to get a tuple that represents the row and col index? i.e. (x, y)

Answer (score 0):

```
import pandas as pd

b = pd.DataFrame(b)

print b[b.duplicated()]
```